# Why Is Using RPi As NAS For Hikvision Camera - SO SLOW!

Tags: networking, camera

For a few years I have been using a Raspberry Pi3 as a NAS drive for my Hikvision CCTV camera to save footage to. I prefer this to a NVR/ DVR, as it is low energy, easy to hide and quiet. I do not want to use a larger server or NVR continually plugged in and running.

However, while watching live footage from the camera is perfectly fine over my network (both on network and remotely, using DDNS), playback of footage recorded to the Pi NAS setup is painfully slow - it plays footage for a second, pauses, a few seconds later another frame, maybe another frame then a pause... you get the idea!

Even scrubbing through the timeline to find footage is slow to refresh, etc, etc.

Please can somebody tell me why this happens, or even better, how to resolve this so I can just watch my footage back as it should be watched?

My setup:

- Hikvision camera connected by POE.
- POE cable uses a POE adapter, connected to a Powerline network extender plug.
- The other powerline extender is plugged into the router in another room with ethernet.
- Pi connected to router with ethernet
- I use OpenMediaVault on the Pi for the NAS setup.
- I use an external USB Western Digital HDD (250GB) for storage (plugged into the USB on the Pi.

I know the extended network with power plug extenders is not ideal but it works, as I can connect to the camera without any glitches or lag in order to view real time. I feel the problem is somewhere within the Pi setup downstream of the camera.

I have googled this to death and end up confusing myself trying to understand what the fix might be.

Thanks
Stu

Comment: You have a slow drive / heavy application / slow ethernet link via power line adapter and a bottleneck on the USB hub in the Pi.  Try a simple Samba share, a decent hard drive, a sensible network and a board designed for passing data around - sorry for being blunt but there's no easy way of saying 'throw it out and start again' !

Comment: Thanks. Blunt is good but what do you mean by 'board'?

Comment: Only have a little space in comments - the Pi board is a great general purpose SBC but lacks in USB controllers and a decent HDD interface - the new 4B Compute Carrier is better https://youtu.be/oWev1THtA04 but still small mini ITX boards knock the spots off Pis - even dual Pentium boards run rings around the Pi with decent HDD and controllers :-(